# Dot product of vectors

Tags: vectors

How do I find the dot product in case of problem 1a exercise 9.3 (advance engineering mathematics Greenberg)
Note: this is for self study.

Diagram in url
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfWsj.jpg

Got it  
$\sin(60^\circ) = \|u\| / \|v\| \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \|v\| = 10 / \sqrt{3}$

$$u\cdot v = \|u\| \|v\| \cos(150^\circ) = 5 \times \frac{10}{\sqrt{3}} \times \frac{- \sqrt{3}} 2 = -25$$

Comment: $$u\cdot v = ||u||||v||\cos\alpha,$$ where $\alpha$ is the angle between...

Comment: Please clarify since the |v| is not given in this case

Comment: $||v||$ is not given, but you have a right angle triangle which you can use.

Comment: Looks about right, yes.

Comment: 5xum thanks for pointing me in right direction.

Comment: @5xum : Notice this difference $||u|| ||v||$ versus $\|u\|\|v\|$.  The former is coded as ||u|| ||v||, and the latter as \|u\| \|v\| and is standard. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

You have $|v|=5\sec 30$, so $u\cdot v=5\times5\times \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\times\cos 150=-25$